# Difference between .contains and :contains in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm reading a book on [jQuery Mobile](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920020585.do) and in the begining it states:

...these selectors can be used either to directly select elements (e.g. `$("div:contains('foo')"))` or they can be used to filter other selectors (e.g.  `$("div").contains('foo')`).

Can someone please explain the difference between these two selectors, because I'm missing the point here.

Comment: They are different in terms of how they work internally, but they will provide the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("div:contains('foo')"))` with the [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector) returns any `div` whose text contains the string `'foo'`.

The only `.contains()` method that I know of is [`$.contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains). You cannot use that on a jQuery result set (i.e. the result of a selection), so `$("div").contains('foo')` won't actually work. In fact, the method `$.contains()` itself works completely differently from the `:contains()` selector; in that it tests whether an element is contained within another element as a descendant.

Frankly, I'm not sure what the book is saying. That statement doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, considering that it even uses examples that aren't real jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no differece between [`.contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) (function) and the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

According to the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js) both are using the same code ("Sizzle" manages the CSS selector functions), line 5350:

```
jQuery.contains = Sizzle.contains;
```

Comment: A quick look at both links leads me to believe that there really is a difference between the function and the selector...